# Search for value in all DataFrame columns (except first column !) and add new column with matching column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to do a search on all columns (except the first column !) of a DataFrame and add a new column (like 'Column_Match') with the name of the matching column.

I tried something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('my_keyword').any(), axis=1)
```

But it's not excluding the first column and I don't know how to return and add the column name.

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('my_keyword').any(), axis=1)` ??

Comment: @anky_91: I assume this is skipping the first column (`iloc[:,1:]`) but how can I add the matching column name a to a new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want columns name of first matched value per rows add new column for match not exist values by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'A':list('abcdef'),
         'C':list('akabbe'),
         'F':list('eakbbb')
})


f = lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('e')
df['new'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f, axis=1).assign(missing=True).idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
   B  A  C  F      new
0  4  a  a  e        F
1  5  b  k  a  missing
2  4  c  a  k  missing
3  5  d  b  b  missing
4  5  e  b  b        A
5  4  f  e  b        C
```

If need all columns names of all matched values create boolean DataFrame and use dot product with columns names by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
f = lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('a')
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f, axis=1)
df['new'] = df1.dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ').replace('', 'missing')
print (df)
   B  A  C  F      new
0  4  a  a  e     A, C
1  5  b  k  a        F
2  4  c  a  k        C
3  5  d  b  b  missing
4  5  e  b  b  missing
5  4  f  e  b  missing
```

Comment: Excellent. The second sample makes it complete !