# Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row and add new column with matching column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In addition on my previous question [Search for value in all DataFrame columns (except first column !) and add new column with matching column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099272/search-for-value-in-all-dataframe-columns-except-first-column-and-add-new-co) (where I used a static keyword)

I'd like to check if the string in the first column is contained in one of the another columns in the same row and then add a new column with the matching column name(s). All columns names of all matched values!

Now i'm using this with a static keyword:

```
keyword='123'
f = lambda row: row.apply(str).str.replace(".","").str.contains(keyword ,na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f, axis=1)

df.insert(loc=1, column='Matching_Columns', value=df1.dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.strip(', '))
```

Sample:

Input:

```
key | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E
------------------------------------
123 | abcd  | 12345 | fght  | 7890
567 | tdfe  | 6353  | 0567  | 56789
```

Output:

```
key | match       | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E
-------------------------------------------------
123 | col_C       | abcd  | 12345 | fght  | 7890
567 | col_D,col_E | tdfe  | 6353  | 0567  | 56789
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful to properly understand the problem.

Comment: I've added some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df
  to_find col1 col2
0       a   ab   ac
1       b   aa   ba
2       c   bc   ee
>>> df['found_in'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.iloc[1:][x.iloc[1:].str.contains(str(x['to_find']))].index), axis=1)
>>> df
  to_find col1 col2   found_in
0       a   ab   ac  col1 col2
1       b   aa   ba       col2
2       c   bc   ee       col1
```

For better readability,

```
>>> def get_columns(x):
...     y = x.iloc[1:]
...     return y.index[y.str.contains(str(x['to_find']))]
... 
>>> df['found_in'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(get_columns(x)), axis=1)
```

Comment: I receive an error on your code: `TypeError: ('first argument must be string or compiled pattern', 'occurred at index 0')`. I changed it to ` return y.index[y.str.contains(str(x['Search_Term']),na=False, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]` and now it looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Another method involving [`df.dot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)

```
m=df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(x['key']),axis=1).iloc[:,1:]
df['match']=m.dot(m.columns+',').str[:-1]
print(df)
```

---

```
   key    col_B  col_C    col_D  col_E        match
0  123   abcd    12345   fght     7890        col_C
1  567   tdfe     6353   0567    56789  col_D,col_E
```

Comment: Nice one, anky. I thought about `dot`, but I forgot completely the way adding `','` to it.  +1

Answer (score 2):

First, `apply` to get boolean dataframe. Next, using `mask` to assign column names to `True` value, replace `False` to `NaN` and `agg` join on `dropna` series:

```
df1 = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[1:].str.contains(x.key), axis=1)
df['match'] = df1.mask(df1, df1.columns[None,:]).replace(False,np.nan) \
                 .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)


Out[41]:
   key col_B  col_C col_D  col_E        match
0  123  abcd  12345  fght   7890        col_C
1  567  tdfe   6353  0567  56789  col_D,col_E
```